# C# - Method inside generic class with additional constraints to T

Tags: c#, oop, generics

I have a generic class `Foo<T> where T: SomeBaseType`.

And in the specific case where `T` is `SpecificDerivedType`, I want my class to have an additional method.

Something like:

```
class Foo<T> where T: SomeBaseType
{
    //.... lots of regular methods taking T, outputting T, etc.

    //in pseudo code
    void SpecialMethod() visible if T: SpecificDerivedType
    {
        //...code...
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't think it is possible, but commenting here to see what will come up

Comment: You can make `SpecialMethod` to be extension method for `Foo<SpecificDerivedType>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I achieve this?

You can't. Create a specialized `Foo`.

```
class SpecialFoo<T> : Foo<T> where T: SpecificDerivedType
{
    void SpecialMethod()
    {
        //...code...
    }
}
```

Other suggest an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods), which is obviously not the same as what you ask. It might be a workaround though.

Comment: Extension methods are an option, but this answer is better because it allows more control of accessibility levels in the other methods.

Answer (score 6):

Make an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) for `Foo<T>`:

```
public static void SpecialMethod<T>(this Foo<T> foo)
    where T : SpecificDerivedType
{
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing quite like that, but you *could* add an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) on `Foo<T>` with a more specific constraint than `T` normally has. Here's a complete example:

```
using System;

class SomeBaseType {}
class SomeDerivedType : SomeBaseType {}

static class FooExtensions
{
    public static void Extra<T>(this Foo<T> foo)
        where T : SomeDerivedType
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You have extra functionality!");
    }
}

class Foo<T> where T : SomeBaseType
{
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)        
    {
        Foo<SomeBaseType> foo1 = new Foo<SomeBaseType>();
        Foo<SomeDerivedType> foo2 = new Foo<SomeDerivedType>();

        // Doesn't compile: the constraint isn't met
        // foo1.Extra();

        // Does compile
        foo2.Extra();
    }
}
```

That allows you to call the method on an existing instance rather than having to create a more specialized instance. On the other hand, it relies on the extension method having enough access to do whatever it needs to in `Foo<T>`. You may need to have an unconstrained `internal` method in `Foo<T>` for `FooExtensions.Extra` to call.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) that will look like this:

```
public static void SpecificMethod<T>(this Generic<T> instance) 
    where T : SpecificDerivedType
```

Comment: That applies the method to `SpecificDerivedType`, not `Foo<SpecificDerivedType>` or `Foo<SomeTypeDerivedFromSpecificDerivedType>`

Comment: oh, indeed, needs to be corrected. since you already posted right answer, I won't bother.

Comment: @Vladislav there is exactly the same answer above, so does not make sense to replicate.

Comment: @SerejaBogolubov deleted my comment already, cause you've added a description. It makes sense to post correct and descriptive answers or nothing. People reading this later (if any) may be confused, don't you think?

Comment: @Vladislav, generally agree, but not in this particular case. Edited not by me, actually. Friedly ghosts are near :)